# Cron error extension - Magento2

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation

I have an error while trying to install **Magento extension**.

**The Error:**

> Error from Setup Application Cron Script: Cron job has not been
>   configured yet Other checks will fail as a result (PHP version, PHP
>   settings, and PHP extensions) Error from Updater Application Cron
>   Script: Cron job has not been configured yet.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your php version? Do You have installed cron? When You have this problem? Have you installed this module propertly?

Comment: I use xampp on osx. Php version is 5.6.24. And yeah i'm afraid that there is no cron running

Comment: I am pretty sure this is issue. When this error occur? Try php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: This error occurs while i'm trying to install a magento extension. 
While run php bin/magento cron:run the terminal says "ran jobs by schedule".

If i ran crontab -u root  -l it says "no crontab for root"

Comment: Been able to configure the cron, now i have errors for the backup

Comment: can You describe it?

Comment: did it, Now i'm on an "update pending" status for the extension installation

Comment: this is the log error 

[2017-03-07 15:51:05] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.travis.yml  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.php_cs  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php.ini.sample  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.htaccess.sample  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.user.ini [] []

Comment: " Found non-writable path". It looks like there is no permisions for save.

Comment: How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Magento looks for the magento user's crontab. If you configured it as root, that will break things.

create a crontab listing the three cron jobs listed in devdocs.magento.com using your magento user, be sure to set it to run every minute, and your issue "should" solve itself after the next cron run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Magento directory** & try to run these commands into **cmd or your terminal**

> php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php update/cron.php
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Than retry to check for the **dependency** for your **extension installation**